# Combine multiple select query result into one final table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, merge, multiple-tables

I am using SQL Server for database purposes.

I have a stored procedure that returns the select query of selected data in it.

Example:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
    (
      UserId int, 
      FullName varchar(200),
      FirstName varchar(200),
      LastName varchar(200),
      Status varchar(10),
      Role varchar(50)
    )
```

I have used this to return condition wise select query data like:

1. if `Role = Admin`, do some select query and insert into `@table1`
2. if `Role = Employee`, do some select query and insert into `@table1`
3. if `Role = Accountant`, do some select query and insert into `@table1`
4. if `Role = Worker`, do some select query and insert into `@table1`

I want a list of all but condition wise so I call above stored procedure again and again condition wise it is time consuming so I thought that I if I take it all at once in one table with Role at last column as name of Role so I can do where condition in my coming result but don't know how to take all in one table that is table1.

If anyone having idea how to do that it is helpful for me so answer it please!

NOTE: All the select query result is same as I have created the table1.

Comment: You don't need to mention the dbms in the subject line since it's properly tagged.

Comment: You probably need to change your stored procedure. If we could see the code perhaps we could help with that.

Comment: Your question is detail, but it would be fine if you provide some sample data and explain what you are trying to achieve with that sample data.

Comment: what is the front-end used ? remove the role condition in the stored procedure or directly consume the table in the code and filter it in the front-end based on the criteria

Comment: there is only select query simple the only change is that role coming data is either Admin or Accountant or Employee or Worker.

Comment: You are probably looking for `UNION ALL` to glue your results together.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes but how I don't know. Can you please give some example.

Comment: in your users table, can a UserID have different roles? if yes you need a 1:N table to link users to roles, if not you should add the role column to your users table and calc it with a trigger on update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already declared the table @table1

Just write your select query with insert into @table1 if no change in all the queries except the role as you have written.

Example:

```
Insert into @table1
your query where Role = Admin
Insert into @table1
your query where Role = Employee
Insert into @table1
your query where Role = Accountant
Insert into @table1
your query where Role = Worker
```

Or you can use below as well (recommended - Jibin's answer)

```
Insert into @table1
your query where Role = Admin
UNION ALL
your query where Role = Employee
UNION ALL
your query where Role = Accountant
UNION ALL
your query where Role = Worker
```

second is recommended because good to collect the resultset via muliptle select statement with union and insert in a single statement which is faster rather than multiple insert so by this you can get all the details in one table.

At back-end side means server side you can than take role wise data using entity framework or any method what ever you prefer to use with:

ex using entity framework:

```
var data = db.storedprocedurename("parameter").ToList();
var adminData = data.where(r => r.Role == "Admin")
var accoutantData = data.where(r => r.Role == "Accountant")
var employeeData = data.where(r => r.Role == "Employee")
var workerData = data.where(r => r.Role == "Worker")
```

Comment: I am confused to use answer of your or Jibin's answer but I am trying since I asked the question just like you have written so I continue with this. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure to help you.

Comment: You can use Jibin's answer as well because good to collect the resultset via muliptle select statement with union and insert in a single statement which is faster rather than multiple insert.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `UNION` of all the result set and then insert it to `@table1`. Something like

```
Insert into @table1
your 1st select query with extra column role
UNION ALL
your 2nd select query with extra column role
UNION ALL
your 3rd select query with extra column role
UNION ALL
your 4th select query with extra column role
```

Comment: It's glad that you give an answer sir really but I am confused to use answer of your or MV's answer but I am trying since I asked the question just like MV's answer so I continue with it still if I goes wrong what is preferable to use please tell me. Thanks

Comment: @padhiyar: We don't know either. We don't know why you decided to use a stored procedure or why you decided for a temporary table. Maybe it would suffice to use a simple query. A view maybe. Maybe your separate queries are not so very different from each other so one could merge them in a smaller and faster query. So the answer is: that depends. If you are fine with 0MV1' answer, find it readable and appropriate, then go wit it. There are often several ways to achieve a goal. Go with a solution that you understand and like.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran thanks for the guide but what is the difference if I use Uninon all instead of insert into? Is there any time consuming or some major difference?

Comment: @padhiyar: The difference should be neglectable. With the `UNION ALL` solution shown here, there is only one `INSERT` statement to execute, which the optimizer may or may not perform quicker than four separate statements.

Comment: @padhiyar I guess Thorsten Kettner had already answered it. It will optimize the code. You don't have to keep writing the insert for all the four select statements.

Comment: Ok thanks for explanation ThorstenKettner so you mean to say I should go with Jibin's answer, right?

Comment: @padhiyar He didn't say that. He said you to go with the solution which you feel is simple and easy to understand.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran ok but sir how do I get to know which is easy and faster every time insert or with union all? That's what I am asking!

Comment: @padhiyar We don't know in what situation you are actually using it. How much data will be there. So you will only have to test both and pick the better solution. And share the output here, so that it will be helpful for others also.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran ok yes I will